# How to get "title" from AJV error?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I've got a JSON Schema that looks like this:

```
{
  "required": [
    "instructions"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "instructions": {
      "title": "Instructions",
      "minItems": 3,
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "required": [
          "typeId",
          "teamId",
          "disciplineId"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "typeId": {
            "minimum": 1,
            "title": "Appointment Type",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "teamId": {
            "minimum": 1,
            "title": "Team",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "disciplineId": {
            "minimum": 1,
            "title": "Discipline",
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "prefClinicianId": {
            "title": "Pref. Clinician",
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "null"
              },
              {
                "minimum": 1,
                "type": "integer"
              }
            ]
          },
          "prefTime": {
            "title": "Pref. Time",
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "null"
              },
              {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            ]
          },
          "childRequired": {
            "title": "Child Req'd",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

As you can see, I've added `title`s to all the properties. However, the error object I get back looks like:

```
[
  {
    "keyword": "minItems",
    "dataPath": ".instructions",
    "schemaPath": "#/properties/instructions/minItems",
    "params": {
      "limit": 3
    },
    "message": "should NOT have less than 3 items"
  },
  {
    "keyword": "type",
    "dataPath": ".instructions[0].typeId",
    "schemaPath": "#/properties/instructions/items/properties/typeId/type",
    "params": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "message": "should be integer"
  },
  {
    "keyword": "type",
    "dataPath": ".instructions[0].teamId",
    "schemaPath": "#/properties/instructions/items/properties/teamId/type",
    "params": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "message": "should be integer"
  },
  {
    "keyword": "type",
    "dataPath": ".instructions[0].disciplineId",
    "schemaPath": "#/properties/instructions/items/properties/disciplineId/type",
    "params": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "message": "should be integer"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the `title` is not in there. How can I get the titles with the errors?

Please note that this question is specific to [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create your AJV object set the [verbose option to true](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#validation-and-reporting-options).

This will add a `parentSchema` property to the ajv error with the original schema.  It will also add a `schema` property that contains the specific schema attribute that caused the validation failure.

Here's an example:

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({
  $data: true,
  verbose: true
});

let schema = {
  title: 'object title',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    str: {
      title: "A string property",
      type: "string"
    }
  }
};

let data = {
  str: 3
};

ajv.validate(schema, data)

console.log('ERRORS: ', this.ajv.errors)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/5.3.0/ajv.bundle.js"></script>
```